# How do I access all the files on a disk image?

Tags: mount, backup, dd, disk, images

To backup a remote server, I ran this command on my local machine: `ssh user@remote "dd if=/dev/vda | gzip -1 -" | dd of=image.gz`

I then decompressed `image.gz` and tried to mount it by double clicking it (i.e. via DiskImageMounter.app) to make sure all the contents are there.

The size of the decompressed image file is about right (the server had a 50 GB disk), but when I mount the image, all I see is a "UEFI" directory in file explorer, which is substantially smaller than the disk of the server and does not contain e.g. the home directory of the server.

This is the info I get from the Disk Utility in MacOS (I presume what I want is in "disk10s1", but all I can access so far is "UEFI".
):

[image: Disk Utility GUI]

Comment: The UEFI partition is a FAT, which MacOS knows how to read.  What filesystem(s) are on the other partitions?  If MacOS doesn't know how to read them, that'd explain why you don't see them in File Explorer.

Comment: FYI: This is not a consistent, reliable backup - you can not reliably clone a systems disk while it is running.

Comment: Also, `/dev/vda` points to this being a VM. The "easy" way here is just use the tools of the virtualizer to export an image.

Comment: @AndyDalton the server is running Ubuntu, so probably something MacOS can read.

Comment: @Panki The system was booted via a recovery ISO. It was not running.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Agreed, but unfortunately the virtualizer does not allow downloading of disk images, so I would have to leave the image hosted with them, meaning A) I have to continue paying for hosting the image and B) I have to count on the virtualizer staying in business for my lifetime — neither of which I want to do. :(

Comment: @JacksonHunt that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @AndyDalton I think you're right after all. The partition I want to read is ext4, and MacOS doesn't read that natively (I wasn't aware )

Answer (score 1):

> I then decompressed image.gz and tried to mount it by double clicking it (i.e. via DiskImageMounter.app) to make sure all the contents are there.

What you have is a full-disk backup. You *haven't*, but had you taken this while `/dev/vda` was rw-mounted, it would at least be slightly broken; it would be probably heavily broken if `image.gz` also resided on `/dev/vda`, as you'd be heavily modifying the file system during the backing up itself.

This means it's not only the partition that contains your data-containing file system, but starts with a partition table, and it seems it contains an UEFI boot partition.

Upon double-clicking, your DiskImageMounter seems to recognize at the very least that partition; that's good.

The others might or might not have been recognized; your operating system simply might not have file system drivers for that.

I'd say: if you want to access the data on that image, simply boot a VM using that disk locally.

If you want a more useful backup, I'd say you should simply back up the *files*, not the *raw disk image* (unless you really just want to replicate the whole VM). There's nothing outside of files and their attributes on a file system – so you don't lose anything just backing up the files.

And that could very trivially be achieved either directly using

```bash
ssh user@remote tar cpf - --xattrs --acls --zstd / > backup.tar.zst
```

which will just run `tar` on the target system to archive all files, compress it using `zstd` (needs to be installed on the remote system) on the fly, `p`reserving all file attributes, `xattrs` and `acls`, and pipe the result through `ssh` to your local machine, which directly writes it to the local file `backup.tar.zst`.

You can also make a smaller archive of all files on the remote in a file on the remote itself (which excludes the backup itself), using `mksquashfs` (needs to be installed), for later download:

```bash
mksquashfs / backup-$(date --utc -Ihours).squashfs -wildcards -exclude '... backup-*.squashfs' -comp zstd
```

The elegant part here is that it's easy exclude any backup file to be included in the backup itself, and that `mksquashfs` inherently saves a lot of space by compressing well and stores the content of identical files only once.

Another elegant aspect is that these squashfs archives can directly be mounted (at least on Linux) – no decompression necessary. On MacOS, you can install `squashfs-tools` to uncompress, and I *think* (never tried), you can use `macFUSE` together with `squashfuse` to also mount them. Have fun!

Comment: The image was taken with the system NOT in operation via a recovery console. Image.gz does not reside on /dev/vda, the output of dd was piped directly to my local machine.

Comment: @JacksonHunt I'm glad to hear that! Is it OK if I leve that parentheses in my answer in, to warn future users (many of whom might not be as experienced as you) about this?

Comment: (by the way, not an optimal use of `dd`; you could just have directly used `gzip -1 < /dev/vda`. Because I think of this answer of a bit helpful just beyond the scope, note that `gzip -1` isn't very compressed, but still pretty slow – `gzip` is single threaded! `pigz` generates the same compressed data, but can use multiple CPU cores. But `zstd` can do that, out of the box, and `zstd -4` is still faster than `pigz -1`, but compresses about as good as `gzip --best`.)

Comment: @JacksonHunt I defused the statement regarding things being mounted significantly.

Comment: I think I found the issue... the partition I want to read is ext4, not natively read by MacOS. I will give your suggested backup methods a try. They seem like good alternatives! Thank you for your engagement! 

Comment: yep, as said in the answer :)

Comment: You're right. Thanks again! For some reason I had it coded in my brain that of course MacOS could natively read anything free that is popularly used in Linux...